# Smart Contract deployment error

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, rinkeby

I am trying to deploy a smart contract on Rinkeby testnet and I am getting the following error

[image]

**truffle-config.js settings**

```
  networks: {
    development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
rinkeby: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${projectId}`),
  network_id: 4,       // Rinkeby's id
  gas: 8500000,        
  gasPrice: 1000000000,  // 1 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
  confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
  timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
  skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
},}
```

I was following the following link for the deployment

https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/create-an-nft-and-deploy-to-a-public-testnet-using-truffle/2961

Comment: Not an answer to your problem but consider not using Rinkeby anymore, since it will become deprecated soon (due to the Merge). Switch to the Goerli testnet.

Comment: Consider using [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) and deploying contracts will be easier.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I am trying to deploy NFT to opensea. Does opensea supports goerli testnet ?

https://docs.opensea.io/reference/rinkeby-api-overview

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that sometimes a transaction with a higher gas price than yours have been submitted around the time as your transaction. You can increase the gas price, and resubmit the transaction later. Also make sure you check the transaction pool of your node to ensure a miner existed in your network.